# Dynamic Plots with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have an equation
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2+v^2+2rvz=1.
\end{equation}
Given a value for $r$ and $v$, I know that the equation is a surface. How do I produce a dynamic plot so that I could see how the surface changes as I vary $r$ and $v$? Also, for a given $r$ and $v$, how can I get sample points (values of $x,y,z$)? Is there a way to do it in tabular form?

Comment: Use `Manipulate`, probably with `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   ContourPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + 2 r v z == 1,
    {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
    ImageSize -> 360],
   FindInstance[
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + 2 r v z == 1,
      {x, y, z}, Reals, n] // N //
    Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &}],
 {{r, 2}, -5, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{v, 2}, -5, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{n, 10, "Number of Samples"}, 5, 50, 5,
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +v^2+2r v z== 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}],{v,-2,2},{r,-2,2}]
```

Also, for the second question, you can use something like this:

`r0=0`

`v0=0`

`{x,y,z}/.FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +v^2+2r v z== 1/.{r->r0,v->v0},{x,y,z},Reals,10]`

That 10 at the end says how many sample points for these values of ***r*** and ***v*** you want.

Comment: But this will be a hypersurface, since there are 5 variables.

Comment: Well if you have given values of `r` and `v` then you only have 3 unknowns?

Comment: @Janus, and how exactly were you expecting a computer program to present a hypersurface?